# Unable to show meta box data in frontend

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox

I am able to show the featured image and the text in the editor but I made some additional custom post types and meta box to show some important data but I am unable to show([highlighted in red in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mfurd.png))

Here's the entire custom post and custom meta box code that I wrote:

```
// enqueue the child theme stylesheet

Function qode_child_theme_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_register_style( 'childstyle', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css'  );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'childstyle' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'qode_child_theme_enqueue_scripts', 11);

// create_post_car_listing function is created to add Car Listings from the admin area
function create_post_car_listing() {
$supports = array(
'title', 
'editor', 
'thumbnail', 
'excerpt', 
'revisions', 
);
$labels = array(
'name' => _x('Car Listings', 'plural'),
'singular_name' => _x('All Listings', 'singular'),
'menu_name' => _x('Car Listings', 'admin menu'),
'name_admin_bar' => _x('Car Listings', 'admin bar'),
'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'add new'),
'add_new_item' => __('Add New Car Listing'),
'new_item' => __('New Car Listing'),
'edit_item' => __('Edit Car Listing'),
'view_item' => __('View Car Listing'),
'all_items' => __('All Listings'),
);
$args = array(
'supports' => $supports,
'labels' => $labels,
'public' => true,
'query_var' => true,
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'car-listing'),
'has_archive' => false,
'hierarchical' => false,
//'taxonomies' => array( 'category'),
);

register_post_type('car_listing', $args);
}
add_action('init', 'create_post_car_listing');

//Adding taxonomies for car listing 

function fuel_type() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'Fuel Type', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Fuel Type', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Fuel Types' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All Fuel Types' ),
        'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Fuel Type' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Fuel Type:' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Fuel Type' ), 
        'update_item' => __( 'Update Fuel Type' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Fuel Type' ),
        'new_item_name' => __( 'New Fuel Type' ),
        'menu_name' => __( 'Fuel Type' ),
    ); 
    register_taxonomy(
        'fuel_type',
        'car_listing',
        array(
            'labels' => $labels,
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'fuel-type' ),
            'hierarchical' => true,
        )
    );

}
add_action( 'init', 'fuel_type' );

//Listing Categories function is used to add the type of fuel a car uses 

function listing_categories() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'Listing Category', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Listing Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Listing Categories' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All Listing Categories' ),
        'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Listing Category' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Listing Category:' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Listing Category' ), 
        'update_item' => __( 'Update Listing Category' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Listing Category' ),
        'new_item_name' => __( 'New Listing Category Name' ),
        'menu_name' => __( 'Listing Categories' ),
    ); 
    register_taxonomy(
        'listing_category',
        'car_listing',
        array(
            'labels' => $labels,
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'listing-categories' ),
            'hierarchical' => true,
        )
    );

}
add_action( 'init', 'listing_categories' );


// Adding custom meta boxes for car listing
function listing_overview_meta_box(){
    add_meta_box( 'listing_overview_box', 'Listing Overview', 'overview_box_content_callback', 'car_listing' );
}
function overview_box_content_callback($post) {
    wp_nonce_field('overview_box_content_savedata', 'listing_overview_meta_box_nonce' );

    $value = get_post_meta( $post -> ID, '_listing_overview_content_key', true );

    echo '<textarea style ="width:100%;" rows="4" cols="50" id="listing_overview_box_content_field" name="listing_overview_box_content_field">' .esc_attr($value). '</textarea>';
}

add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'listing_overview_meta_box');

function overview_box_content_savedata ($post_id) {

    if ( ! isset ( $_POST['listing_overview_meta_box_nonce'])){
        return;
    }

    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['listing_overview_meta_box_nonce'], 'overview_box_content_savedata') ){
        return;
    }

    if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ){
        return;
    }

    if( ! current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id) ){
        return;
    }

    if( ! isset( $_POST['listing_overview_box_content_field'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $overview_data = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['listing_overview_box_content_field'] );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_listing_overview_content_key', $overview_data );
}

add_action('save_post', 'overview_box_content_savedata' );
```

Comment: Image you shared has no red highlighted area. Share the code which fails to display data on front-end.

Comment: I don't see any connection between the code and image you provide. Also, please remove everything does not belonging to meta data: post type and taxonomy registration, scripts.

Comment: Updated the image

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to display the data mentioned in your question.

```
// use within loop 
echo get_post_meta( $post -> ID, '_listing_overview_content_key', true );
```

**Example:**

```
/**
* Setup query to show the 'car_listing' post type with '8' posts.
* Output is title with excerpt, Listing Overview, Fuel Type an Listing Category.   
*/
   $args = array(  
       'post_type' => 'car_listing',
       'post_status' => 'publish',
       'posts_per_page' => 8,
       'orderby' => 'title',
       'order' => 'ASC',
   );

   // get posts
   $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
   if ( $loop->have_posts() )  {    
       while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
           <article>
               <h2><?php   the_title();  ?></h2>
               <p><?php    the_excerpt();  ?></p>
               <h3>Listing Overview:</h3>
               <p>
                   <?php  echo get_post_meta( $post -> ID, '_listing_overview_content_key', true ); ?>
               </p>
               <?php the_terms( $post->ID, 'fuel_type', '<br>Fuel Type: ', ' , ' ); ?>
               <?php the_terms( $post->ID, 'listing_category', '<br>Listing Category: ', ' , ' ); ?>
           </article>
   <?php
       endwhile;
 }

   wp_reset_postdata();
```

I hope this helps.

**EDIT**
In templates for custom post type ( `archive-car-listing.php` and `single-car-listing.php` ), the code should look like something

```
if ( have_posts() )  {    
           while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
               <article>
                   <h2><?php   the_title();  ?></h2>
                   <p><?php    the_excerpt();  ?></p>
                   <h3>Listing Overview:</h3>
                   <p>
                       <?php  echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_listing_overview_content_key', true ); ?>
                   </p>
                   <?php the_terms( $post->ID, 'fuel_type', '<br>Fuel Type: ', ' , ' ); ?>
                   <?php the_terms( $post->ID, 'listing_category', '<br>Listing Category: ', ' , ' ); ?>
               </article>
       <?php
           endwhile;
     }
```

Comment: Really appreciate prompt reply. Could you please tell how do I apply loop over this?

Comment: @Rahul Answer updated to include an example loop.

Comment: Do I need to add this in functions.php ?

Comment: @Rahul NOT FOR `functions.php`, you should put this where you want to display data on front-end, in template files.

Comment: I created it as a post type( https://i.imgur.com/QTWOEGC.png) and if I add that code in a template file I don't think I will be able to select it because it's not a page but a post type. Please tell me if I am wrong.

Comment: You need to create archive-car-listing.php and single-car-listing.php files in your theme folder. [See this](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/custom-post-type-template-files/) for detail. In that case you will also need to change the code in my answer.

Comment: @Rahul See updated answer please. You can easily create templates for custom post type ( `archive-car-listing.php` and `single-car-listing.php` ) by creating copies of  `archive.php` and `single.php` of your theme files.